# How to fix Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now?

Tags: ios, crash, admob

I got random crash in my application with the following reason: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug.

```
_WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x78695e90: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   0xb1e3698 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
2   0x5dc99de __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
3   0x5dc9920 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
4   0x5dbf22f __CFRunLoopRun
5   0x5dbebcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   0x5dbe9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   0xb1e3660 RunWebThread(void*)
8   0x742eecf _pthread_body
9   0x742ee45 _pthread_body
10  0x742cf0e thread_start
```

I got this issue while I am using AdMob in my application.